# mdadm raid5 read error not correctable

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid-5, bad-sectors, mdadm

I have a software raid5 setup existing of 4 disks.
sda, sdb, sdc, sdd
Since everything was up and running I wanted to test the array. To do this I pulled the plug on one of the disks (sdd).
Everything went fine so I tried re-adding the disk with `mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdd`, mdadm was rebuilding the array so after a couple of hours I checked and something went wrong, sdc failed.

Long story short: sdc has some bad sectors, when mdadm reads from these sectors it fails.

In /var/log/messages I can see:

> read error not correctable (sector 753682864 on sdc).

I can not --assemble the array as it sees sdc and sdd as faulty.

I can however `mdadm /dev/md0 --create --assume-clean -l5 -n4 /dev/sd[abc] missing`. After this I tried to add sdd but without success.

When mdadm fails and it reports the sector in /var/log/messages I can verify this by executing `hdparm --read-sector [sector] /dev/sdc`.
When I overwrite the sector using `hdparm --write-sector` it gets replaced and then it functions again. But this is a very time consuming process.

Are there any ways how I can recover from this mess? Would mirroring sdc to sdd (with dd) and then adding sdd as the missing drive help?

Comment: How many bad sectors are there?  If there are only a few, then fix them with hdparm.  If there are many, then toss the drive and restore from backup.

Comment: Like any good administrator I don't have a backup. I assumed raid 5 would provide enough redundancy. I don't know how many bad sectors there are but it looks like it's quite random. I'm going to replace the sata cable first, then try again.

Comment: RAID5 is not a substitute for backup, they serve *completely* different purposes. If you accidentally delete a file or a software bug issues a file delete or wipe command, the RAID 5 array will dutifully destroy the data on all drives.

Comment: I know, but raid 5 suits my needs

Comment: If you don't have a backup, then your data is already gone.  Lesson learned.

Comment: Replacing the cable fixed the problem. Raid is up and running. All is fine. To the backup comments: Making a backup is a choice. I have 4 500GB drives in a raid 5. I'm not investing in another set of drives to make a backup, things are worth the risk since this is a private setup. If the costs of the replacement are less than the costs of a backup, I don't make the backup. The "Like any good administrator I don't have a backup" is sarcastic, as 90% of IT-professionals don't backup their private data. ;-) Thanks for any help though.

Comment: Re: "RAID is not backup because it won't help you with rm -rf". This is not an insurmountable problem: use LVM to create a snapshot alongside the live volume on the same md array. If you delete the wrong thing, or everything, or the filesystem gets corrupted somehow, just restore to the snapshot. Sure, things can go wrong there too but it's much less likely and there are risks of failure in ANY backup or redundancy strategy. It's all about managing risk.